# Mschart activex-set a specific color for specific column

Tags: vba, vb6, mschart

I have a Mschart ActiveX containing one series. I'd like to set the color of a certain bar.
This code works well

```
For i = 1 To .Column
            .Plot.SeriesCollection(i).DataPoints(-1).DataPointLabel.LocationType = VtChLabelLocationTypeAbovePoint
            .Plot.SeriesCollection(i).DataPoints(-1).DataPointLabel.ValueFormat = "##0.0%"
        Next
```

But the following command returns a error

```
DataPoint=3
MSChart1.Plot.SeriesCollection(1).DataPoints(DataPoint).Brush.FillColor.Set 255, 255, 255
```

[image]

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: Do you have at least 1 Series and 3 DataPoints?

Comment: yes at least 10 DataPoints and 1-2 series

Comment: Based on the error message, I would recommend setting a break point on the line that throws the error and inspect the following:  MSChart1.Plot.SeriesCollection.Count and MSChart1.Plot.SeriesCollection(1).DataPoints.Count.

Comment: It shows the right data. Looks like Datapoints property accepts only -1